# JavaScript First Letter Capitalisation Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Firstly, this is my first time working with JavaScript so it is probably just me missing something very simple.

All I want to do is get the value of a text box and make an alert with the first letter capitalised. I have everything working, the first letter isn't actually being capitalised.

This is how I am calling the function:

```
else
{
    input = document.getElementById("search").value;
    'input'.search();
    alert(input);
}
```

This is the function it self:

```
function search(string)
{
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: You are calling your function on a text literal, and you are not doing anything with its return value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capitalize the first letter of string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the correct code

```
else
{
    input = document.getElementById("search").value;
    input =search(input);
    alert(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input = search(input);
```

Instead of:

```
'input'.search();
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't changing `input` at all. Try:

```
else
{
    input = document.getElementById("search").value;
    alert(search(input));
}
```

If you want to permanently change `input` Try:

```
else
{
    input = document.getElementById("search").value;
    input = search(input);
    alert(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things wrong here,

firstly,

```
search(input)
```

instead of

```
'input'.search()
```

secondly,

`string` is immutable so you'll have to do,

```
input = search(input);
alert(input);
.
.
.
function search(str) {
    return (str.replace(str.charAt(0), str.charAt(0).toUpperCase()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not pretty clear to me, but I assume that you want, if your input string is "hello" , you want the output as "Hello".

Try this

call the method and alert the message:-

```
alert(search(input));
```

in the method:-

```
return Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(0)) + input.substring(1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't think about need the .substring so this saved me some time. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+this.slice(1);
}

var searchField = document.getElementById("search");
var query = searchField.value;
searchField.value = query.capitalize();

function search(query) {
   // query api or something...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The answers are correct, but you will have only the first letter in the alert box.
If you don't want only the first letter, here is the solution:

```
function search(string)
{
    return string.substring(0,1).toLocaleUpperCase() + string.substring(1);
}
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/30123193/2379208

Comment: It would be better to flag it as a duplicate than to take an answer from the question I linked and post it.